# Unable to add multiple objects to NSArray

Tags: objective-c

I have a for-loop that iterates over an NSrray, takes objects from that array and adds them to a different NSArray..  I'm finding that only one object is being added to the array...   I think the issue is because there is only one instance of 'TimeSliceinfo'?

Code:

```
for (int z = 0; z < timeProfiles.count; z+= 12) {       

  for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {//Time slices (12)

    NSArray *tP = [timeProfiles objectAtIndex:z + i];


    TimeScaleInfo  *timeScaleInfo0 = [[TimeScaleInfo alloc] initWithTimeScaleID:[timeProfiles[0][2] integerValue]  timeSliceID:[[tP objectAtIndex:15] integerValue] timeScaleStartTime:timeProfiles[0][3] timeScaleEndTime:timeProfiles[0][4] weekdayFlag:weekDayFlag0 clendarFlag:@"00000000"];
    TimeScaleInfo  *timeScaleInfo1 = [[TimeScaleInfo alloc] initWithTimeScaleID:[timeProfiles[1][2] integerValue]  timeSliceID:[[tP objectAtIndex:15] integerValue] timeScaleStartTime:timeProfiles[1][3] timeScaleEndTime:timeProfiles[1][4] weekdayFlag:weekDayFlag1 clendarFlag:@"00000000"];
    TimeScaleInfo  *timeScaleInfo2 = [[TimeScaleInfo alloc] initWithTimeScaleID:[timeProfiles[2][2] integerValue]  timeSliceID:[[tP objectAtIndex:15] integerValue] timeScaleStartTime:timeProfiles[2][3] timeScaleEndTime:timeProfiles[2][4] weekdayFlag:weekDayFlag2 clendarFlag:@"00000000"];
    TimeScaleInfo  *timeScaleInfo3 = [[TimeScaleInfo alloc] initWithTimeScaleID:[timeProfiles[3][2] integerValue]  timeSliceID:[[tP objectAtIndex:15]integerValue] timeScaleStartTime:timeProfiles[3][3] timeScaleEndTime:timeProfiles[3][4] weekdayFlag:weekDayFlag3 clendarFlag:@"00000000"];

    timeSliceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10000];


    // add timescales to timeslice
    TimeSliceInfo *timesliceInfo = [[TimeSliceInfo alloc] initWithTimeSliceID:[[tP objectAtIndex:15] integerValue]  timeScaleInfoArray:@[timeScaleInfo0, timeScaleInfo1, timeScaleInfo2, timeScaleInfo3, timeScaleInfo4, timeScaleInfo5, timeScaleInfo6, timeScaleInfo7, timeScaleInfo8, timeScaleInfo9, timeScaleInfo10, timeScaleInfo11]];


    //add timeslices
    [timeSliceArray addObject:timesliceInfo];
  }
}

// timeSliceArray only contains a single object
 userKeyInfo.timeSliceInfoArray = timeSliceArray;
```

Comment: Initialize `timeSliceArray` before the first `for` loop, not inside the loops.

Comment: Aren't you blatting it with `timeSliceArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10000];`?